# Mathematical formalism of Gradient Boosting Decision Trees (GBDT) algorithms

Tags: boosting, gradient-descent, gradient

I'm trying to better figure out some formalism behind the *Gradient Boosting Decision Trees (GBDT)* algorithms.

Given a dataset $\mathcal{D}$ and a loss function $L : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the gradient boosting algorithm iteratively constructs a model $F:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to minimize the *empirical risk* $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}[L(f(\textbf{x}), y)]$. At each iteration $t$, the model is updated as:

$$F^{(t)}(\textbf{x}) = F^{(t-1)}(\textbf{x}) + \varepsilon h^{(t)}(\textbf{x}) \, \, .$$

where $h^{(t)}(\textbf{x})$ is a *weak* learner chosen from some family of functions.

I don't figure out so well why this weak learner $h$ is chosen to approximate the **negative gradient**  $$\, \, -g^{(t)}(\textbf{x},y) := - \frac{\partial L(y,s)}{\partial s}|_{s=F^{(t-1)}(\textbf{x})}$$

and then the weak learner is taken to be:

$$h^{(t)} = arg \min_{h \in \mathcal{H}} \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}[(-g^{(t)}(\textbf{x},y)-h(\textbf{x}))^2]$$

Could anybody explain me a little better the intuition behind the last 2 equations?

Comment: have you read elements of statistical learning explanation https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf

Comment: can you be more specific? Chapter? Page?

Comment: There's a constraint: the new loss should be smaller than the old loss